# How to have custom message in JOI Validation

Tags: node.js, validation, schema, joi

I am new to NodeJS and need help. I am using JOI as schema validation and I need to have the custom message for each validation. Like if min(3) is there I want custom message and if same field has required then I want different custom message for that.

Please suggest link to any example where I can achieve this. Below is what I was trying.

```
const schema = {
    name: Joi.string().min(3).error((error) => "Min 3 Characters").required().error((error) => "Field is required")
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
const schema = {
  name: Joi.string()
    .min(3)
    .required()
    .options({
      language: {
        any: { required: 'is required' },
        string: { min: 'must be at least 3 Characters' },
      },
    }),
}
```

Answer (score 2):

add error to the end of your validation.

```
var schema = Joi.object().keys({
      firstName: Joi.string().min(5).max(10).required().error(new Error('Give your error message here for first name')),
      lastName: Joi.string().min(5).max(10).required().error(new Error('Give your error message here for last name'))
      ..
    });
```

there is also more stuff you can do if you explore the error function

```
firstname: Joi.string()
      .max(30)
      .min(5)
      .required()
      .label('First Name')
      .error((err) => {
        const errs = err.map(x => `${x.flags.label} ${x.type}(${x.context.limit}) with value ${x.context.value}`);
        console.log(errs);
        return errs.toString();
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://hapi.dev/family/joi/?v=16.1.6#anyerrorerr) you could do something like this:

```
const schema = Joi.string().error(new Error('Was REALLY expecting a string'));
schema.validate(3);     // returns Error('Was REALLY expecting a string')
```